# Testing confirmable(devise) while running on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, actionmailer

I'm new to cucumber in rails and I'm using the `Devise` gem for authentication in a `Rails3` app. I want to test the email confirmation functionality available with the `confirmable` module provided with the `Devise` gem. My tests are working fine but since I'm running the app on `localhost` I cant figure out a way to test the functionality of the app in my browser as the `ActionMailer` is not able to send the email to the registered account. How can I do this? Do I need to disable the `confirmable` module of Devise for subsequent testing on browser or can I setup my `Actionmailer` to send emails to registered accounts.
Thanks a lot

Comment: This isn't the right answer but you could always open up the command line, and use `rails console` or `rails db` to edit a certain user's confirmable attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little ambigiuous. You *could* configure the test/dev environment to actually send email, but what then? Are you going to parse that email for the link with the confirmation token?

If your business logic allows for it, you may want to consider setting `config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 1.minute` in the **device.rb** initializer.

That setting allows the user to log in for the given period of time even while the email address is unconfirmed. In effect, users will be able to use your platform right away and your tests will no longer require to cope with confirmation.

Note that for *manual* testing in dev, you can copy the confirmation link from **development.log**.

As a personal advice, I'd ditch Cucumber altogether unless this is a project for a client who explicitly demands BDD. On most projects you'll be find with the default testing tools at hand.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's a `confirmed_at` field that gets set when a user is confirmed.